# Couldnt find error in: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, random, printing, seed

```
from random import seed, randint, random    
seed()
print ( "A random number between 1 and 10 is", randint(1, 10) )
print ( "Another is", randint(1, 10) )    
seed(0)
print ( "3 random numbers are:", random(), random(), random() )
seed(0)
print ( "The same 3 numbers are:", random(), random(), random() )
```

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-3f5f0d61a508> in <module>()
      2 
      3 seed()
----> 4 print ( "A random number between 1 and 10 is", randint(1, 10) )
      5 print ( "Another is", randint(1, 10) )
      6 

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

---

I have tried adding in commas, deleting the shown line, and all it does is just showing me theres an error on the upcoming print() lines. What went wrong?

Ive also checked, and some people say it mightve been my browsers problem. Is it true? Im currently using jupyter notebook on Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I just ran your code without any exception.

Comment: @khelwood Any problems with it?

Comment: It didn't raise any exceptions, so as far as I can tell, your code does not reproduce the problem you are describing.

Comment: @BcK That wouldn't raise an exception.

Comment: @BcK Im sure Im using Python 3 right now

Comment: Try to clear variables if you use interactive environment?